# Can Grid be used as a Price Modifier in Cartthrob? I have problems mapping price and inventory

Tags: cartthrob, grid

I am trying to use the Grid fieldtype as a price modifier for Cartthrob. Documentation is lacking on this, it only describes Matrix. I have set it up like Matrix, but obviously change tags to Grid tags.

I am also using the exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form so we can add multiple options and quantities at the same time.

I can add multiple product options to the cart, but cannot get the price or the inventory as per the documentation for Matrix.

My product_options fieldnames are options_value, price, inventory, and I have mapped the inventory and price to my product_options field in Cartthrob, but adding to the cart states "Product is out of stock" for all options. If I remove the inventory mapping, I can add them to the cart but then the price is 0.

So it seems I cannot map price and inventory to a grid field, like the docs say you can for Matrix. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Here is exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form form:

```
{exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form return="cart" }

{product_options}
<input type="hidden" name="entry_id[{product_options:count}]" value="{entry_id}">
<input type="hidden" name="item_options[{product_options:count}][product_options]" value="{product_options:option_value}">
<input type="text" name="quantity[{product_options:count}]" value="{product_options:count}">
{/product_options}

<input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" />

{/exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form}
```

We are using the latest CT version 2.5 and EE 2.7.2

Thanks

Comment: I found one issue with my code, I corrected it now. That is the name of the options field must be the name in the item_options field, e.g. name="item_options[{product_options:count}][product_options]"

Comment: I have also tested this with Matrix and it is indeed working (using Matrix tags), so it seems Grid either does not work, or I am doing something wrong

Comment: I tried using grid as a price modifier for CartThrob and it didn't work for me either. I can only assume it is not supported. I used Matrix and that worked.

Comment: Yes am using Matrix for the time being, a real shame now that we have grid.

Answer (score 1):

No, CartThrob does not support using a Grid field for price modifiers.

Comment: Thanks Derek, thought not, but do you mind me asking how you know so I can be sure? And if you know of any plans to introduce it? Thanks

Comment: It's not mentioned in the [docs](http://cartthrob.com/docs/pages/price_modifiers/index.html), nor the [release notes](http://cartthrob.com/docs/pages/change_log/), and CartThrob have unfortunately been very slow to support new EE versions/features, making it even more unlikely that it would have been implemented, without comment, in the span of a single version (Grid was introduced in EE 2.7).

Comment: I guess you're right then :(